# Zeros of Function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ - What's the shape?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I know that the zeros of a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ will from $(n-1)$-dimensional surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (unless the function itself is zero). Is this also true for a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$? If I decompose a complex function $f$ as

$$f(\textbf{x}) = u(\textbf{x}) + v(\textbf{x})i,$$

for some functions $u$ and $v$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then it seems that the zeros of $f$ will be the intersections of the surfaces formed by the zeros of $u$ and $v$, which will be $(n-2)$-dimensional surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$, except for the special cases of $u = v$, in which case the zeros will still form $(n-1)$-dimensional surfaces, and the case of $f=0$.

However, if we decompose the complex function as

$$f(\textbf{x}) = \rho(\textbf{x})e^{i\theta(\textbf{x})},$$

for some functions $\rho$ and $\theta$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then the zeros of $f$ are simply the zeros of $\rho$, which must form $(n-1)$-dimensional surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Which argument above is right? Why is the other wrong? Is there some subtlety with the continuity of a complex function that I'm missing?

Comment: One problem will be that $\theta$ will not necessarily be well-defined... so that the very set-up has problems.

Comment: ... and I should have been more pointed: exactly when the function's values are near $0$, e.g., go _around_ $0$, $\theta$ cannot be continuous...

Comment: "I know that the zeros of a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ will from $(n-1)$-dimensional surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (unless the function itself is zero). " That's false, big time. Consider $f(x)=|x|^2$ for example.